Setting parameter rules in OpenAPI
I am starting to learn API documentation with YAML. I have the below YAML and my query params are id, firstName and lastName. The user should provide either id or any of firstName or lastName.

If id is provided, lastName and firstName need not be provided
if lastName or firstName is provided, id need not be provided

Some what like id or (firstName or lastName).
So how can I define this rule in my YAML. I think oneOf, anyOf constructs can be used for the same in request body but how can I achieve this in a query param ?
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Example API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /users:
    get:
      summary: Get user information by ID or name
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: query
          schema:
            type: integer
          required: false
          description: User ID
        
        - name: firstName
          in: query
          schema:
            type: string
          required: false
          description: First name of the user
        
        - name: lastName
          in: query
          schema:
            type: string
          required: false
          description: Last name of the user
      
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string
                example: User information retrieved successfully

        '400':
          description: Bad request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  error:
                    type: string
                    example: Invalid request parameters


Does this answer your question? -- How to define mutually exclusive query parameters in OpenAPI

This question is similar to: How to define mutually exclusive query parameters in Swagger (OpenAPI)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is not something supported by OpenAPI in the current form.
There has been some discussion about encoding query parameters as a schema object and then you can use JSON Schema constructs like you mentioned.. oneOf or anyOf
This is highly unlikely to be supported by many tools because it wasn't something originally considered until very recently
The idea is you define a single parameter and the tooling can parse it as a schema and extract the properties with explode: true, style: form.
You can give it a shot
openapi: '3.0.3'
info:
  title: test
  version: '1'
paths:
  '/thing':
    parameters:
      - name: query_prop_name
        in: query
        style: form
        explode: true
        schema:
          oneOf:
            - required:
                - id
              type: object
              properties:
                id:
                  type: integer
              additionalProperties: false
            - required:
                - firstName
                - lastName
              type: object
              properties:
                firstName:
                  type: string
                lastName:
                  type: string
              additionalProperties: false



you would end up with a request like
GET /thing?id=1 HTTP/1.1

OR
GET /thing?firstName=test&lastName=thing HTTP/1.1

